# docker-compose rails rake db:reset fails, "cannot drop the currently open database"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I can't seem to reset my database while using docker compose. I've tried killing the server, killing just the database, and restarting the machine.

Anyone know the best way to clear out the development database?

Here's what I tried:

```
docker-compose run web rake db:reset
```

I am getting this error:

> PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database
>   : DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "postgres"
>   Couldn't drop database 'postgres'
>   rake aborted!

I'm using the setup exactly as described by the docker-compose quickstart: https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/

I have a rails container and a postgres container

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the wrong database.

The database `postgres` is normally not used for user data, but for administrative purposes. For example, if you want to drop a database, you have to be connected to a different database in the PostgreSQL database cluster to issue the SQL statement `DROP DATABASE`. Normally, the database `postgres` is used for that purpose, and I have no doubt that Docker does exactly that when it tries to drop a database.

If you really want to drop the database `postgres`, you'd have to connect to some other database in the cluster. The correct solution, however, is to keep your data in a different database. Then the problem should go away by itself.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly the problem - all I needed to do was change the database name in config/database.yml so that it was not postgres. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Same, I was following the same tutorial and had the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: I just added a PR to change the documentation. Hopefully it will be merged and save other postgres noobs the trouble.